# Viewport with scale=1 fill only a part of screen after user scale (iPhone/iPod)

Tags: html, ios, iphone, scale, viewport

I need to convert scalable page to constrained mobile-oriented page. To implement it I insert this `<meta>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,
                               minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, 
                               user-scalable=no"/>
```

Usually it works well and the page transforms from this (on the left) to this (on the right):

[image: scalable page] [image: page with viewport=1]

But if a user scales the page beforehand,  the viewport is set ugly, as it is shown below. Here `window.innerWidth == 319`, `document.body.clientWidth == 320`. So it looks like viewport is zoomed out too. If you rotate the device to landscape mode and back, it becomes looking good (as above, on the right). But I couldn't find a way to fix it programmatically. I tried to

- play with meta's content, remove and add the meta again;
- enable/disable hardware acceleration;
- change properties `display`, `overflow`, `position` for elements `body` and `html`;

but neither helped me. Maybe I need some combo of such magic words, I don't know. Interesting thing is that the problem occurs even if user zooms in and then zooms out returning page's scale to 1.

[image: page with viewport=1 and grey fields]

Here is [the test page](http://kirikaza.github.io/viewport.html) and here is [its source](https://github.com/kirikaza/kirikaza.github.io/blob/master/viewport.html). For those who want to play with the page, I would recommend to close a tab in iOS Safari and then open a new tab again, since the browser sometimes remembers the previous scale during refresh (and even retyping URL in the same tab).

I have no idea now, so any your thoughts would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I used to embrace disabling user scaling, but I have learned that it it's just a huge pain to you and your user to get it to work properly. But you can look here for the answer. http://blog.pgrady.com/post/29511322784/fixing-the-ios-orientation-bug-in-three-steps

Comment: Good post! However, these three tricks don't solve my problem.

Comment: That's a weird problem! You could try jquery `resize()` http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: @DavidCorbin, what do you suggest to perform on resize?

Comment: Actually this might work. `document.getElementByTagName("body")[0].style.width = "100%";`

Comment: I tried your code and cant reproduce the problem when I add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> at the very beginning of <head>

Comment: Is it possible to put whole code with all the CSS and scripts?

Comment: @Carlos the whole source is here: https://github.com/kirikaza/kirikaza.github.io/blob/master/viewport.html

Comment: @Rudolfwm, did you scale the page beforehand?

Comment: Apparently this is a safari mobile bug, read this [article](http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/) for a possible fix (Im not sure if it fits your requirements)